# Batch Convert Black Background to AlphaChannel (XNConvert)

Tags: transparency, batch-processing

On trying to extract the **alphachannel from a image with a blackbackground**,XNconvert doesn't convert black to alpha.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Also are there any other softwares which allow ***batch conversion to alpha channel***?

***Output has no transparency - Black Background***
[image: Black Texture]

***XNconvert Output***
[image: XNconvert]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do here. What is the desired end result? I'm not familiar with XNconvert, but it seems you ask the program to *extract* the alpha channel (if any). That should result in a grayscale image with no transparency. Are you trying to make all black transparent, so you end up with an image of the white shape with transparent background?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you seem to want to make an image of the white shape, where the black parts are transparent.

I don't normally use XnConvert. I just downloaded it, and was able to find this solution:

[image]

First add a *Levels* action. Pull the white slider all the way to the left to make the image completely white.

Then add a *Add mask* action. Use the image as the mask.

The problem is, that this of course can't easily be batched because you need to choose the image for the mask for each image.

---

I would normally use Photoshop for something like this, but if you don't have access to that, I'm sure the free [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) could be used to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah,this works great,barring for the batch export.... I am trying to achieve this with ImageMagick but the greyscale opacity is rendered as Opaque Black.

Comment: @starzar, I don't really know ImageMagick or how you are trying to use it, but basically what you want to do is: move/map for example the red channel to the alpha channel and then make both the red, green and blue channel all white.

Comment: Just a sec.. I will post it as a question .